# Best Approch for bulk insert to Acces database in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I working on windows appliaction which uses Microsoft access as database with oldedb data provider.
In this project I used to import xml file and write the data to database.
I want do bulk insert instead of inserting one record at one time.
So I tried with DAO approch but sometimes ended up with the exception like

"Currently locked unable to update"

Here is the code I used.

```
using TEST = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;

Pubic void Insert()
{

        string sBaseDirectory = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).ToString();
            string sODBPath = sBaseDirectory + @"\TEST.accdb";
            TEST.DBEngine dbEngine = new TESt.DBEngine();
            TEST.Database db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(sODBPath);
            TEST.Recordset rsTest = db.OpenRecordset("dtTest");
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
                {
                    rsTest.AddNew();
                    rsTest.Fields["ID"].Value =i;
                    rsTest.Fields["Name"].Value ="Test";
                    rsTest.update();

                 }
        rsTest.close();
        db.close();

}
```

With Oldedb:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

    string TableSQl = "Select * from dtTest where ID=0";
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter=new OleDbDataAdapter(TableSQl,ConnectionString);
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(INSERT);
    OleDbConnection OleConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);

       for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
          dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ID", OleDbType.BigInt, 8,i.ToString());
          dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", OleDbType.BigInt, 8, "test");              
    }

    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Connection = OleConn;
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Connection.Open();  
    dataAdapter.update(dt);        
    dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();
```

here its not inserting the records in table.

Please guide what is wrong with this code and good approach as well.

Comment: In the second example you add 1000 parameters called 'Id' and 1000 called 'Name'. Shouldn't you be adding the parameters once only and then inserting records into the DataTable?

Comment: it was just example. Ultimately my intention is  how can I insert 1000 records at one shot.

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.80).aspx - 'Using Parameters with a DataAdapter'

> The Add method of the Parameters collection takes the name of the
>   parameter, the DataAdapter specific type, the size (if applicable to
>   the type), and **the name of the SourceColumn from the DataTable**.

So you need to create the parameters correctly, populate the DataTable, and then call Update.

Is there any documentation to suggest that this approach will batch the inserts rather than doing them one at a time anyway?